# highcharts y axis value display left

Tags: highcharts, display, yaxis

I want to change the display position of the chart y axis value.
In the example chart, the y-axis values are displayed to the right of the entire chart.
But I want to display it on the left rather than on the right.
What to do in this case?

[enter link description here](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/stock/basic-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `opposite` property:

```
yAxis: {
  opposite: false
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wx0qdypt/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/yAxis.opposite

Comment: Thank you.
Thanks to you, we are solving the problem!